# Base 64 Content in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

We are receiving a base64encoded string from apex webservices and we have to display that as pdf whenever user clicks on a button. currently we have the below code

```
var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
        if(!isIE){
            window.location.href='data:application/pdf;base64,{!encodedbody}';
        }
        else{
            var b64dt = "{!encodedbody}";
            var contTyp = "application/pdf";
            var dblob = b64toBlob(b64dt,contTyp);
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(dblob, "testdoc.pdf");
        }

function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    var sliceSize = 512;
    b64Data = b64Data.replace(/^[^,]+,/, '');
    b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var byteCharacters = window.atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

which is working for smaller docs (<2 mb) and larger docs are working only in firefox.

I went throuugh this link "https://craignicol.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/excellent-export-and-the-chrome-url-limit/" and tried to use CreateObjectUrl but couldnt get it work.

Comment: What does "not working" entail?

Comment: Are you calling the webservice from JavaScript? Can't you use render as pdf functionality?

Comment: if the document is more than 2 mb then chrome/IE is not displaying the doc.

Comment: We are calling the webservice in visuaforce controller and storing the response file content in a variable which we are using in java script for datauri

Comment: Anyway, we ended up using Attachment object to store the pdf and then using page reference to show the doc in browser using attachment id and standard salesforce method "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=".